Unreal Engine 5.3.2 Launch Bug - Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000001440
UPDATE: I think the root of the problem is here: 
It can`t see my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, or it is broken, so that is probably the reason.
After launching Unreal Engine 5.3.2 this is what I get:
Unhandled Exception: EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION reading address 0x0000000000001440
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_D3D12RHI
UnrealEditor_RHI
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
UnrealEditor
kernel32
ntdll
Interestingly enough, I am able to launch my projects through Epic Games or from the project folder directly => the project is launched successfully in UE5 and I can proceed working there. However if I launch the app itself, Unreal Engine launcher, the above mentioned error occurs.
I am also getting this notification in the project:
Missing support for advanced rendering features
Moreover, somehow lots of games, Unreal Engine based, started having lags. Dead by Daylight for example has recently moved to Unreal Engine and I can`t play it without lags with lowest settings possible. Mordhau had always been fine, but yesterday I checked it and attack animations were broken. Unreal Engine app itself has become much more laggy as well.
I tried various methods, reinstalled UE5, tried some shamanism with Config .ini files, etc. Nothing has helped so far.
I can assume smth is wrong with my gpu.  I am not a Computer Science professional, neither am I an experienced game dev, I have only recently started diving into this, so please don`t judge too harshly.
Thanks in advance.

You can find the experts in the Unreal forums.

This is related to your DirectX. You must check your graphics is at least in minimum requirement category and if so update your drivers.
Source: https://www.reddit.com/r/unrealengine/comments/16ka003/ue_53_startup_crash/.

Thanks, I will be trying to solve this.

Tried updating my GeForce GTX 1050 drivers, didn`t help, installed older versions, no result.

What's the version of your DirectX? Probably it should be updated if 12th version causes this bug.

Direct x 12. https://i.sstatic.net/UGv9r.png this is the problem I think - It can`t see my NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050, or it is broken, so that is probably the reason.  "There is a problem with NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 device. For more information, search for 'graphics device driver error code 43' "
